# vb6 extracting this data from txt file

Tags: vb6

I am using `if` statement to read a string in txt file if it exists then execute my code, now am trying to find a better way of doing this rather than adding multiple `if` statements to detect this specific string.

Any string that contains `NOT FOUND` or `b.1j NOT FOUND (tried in 99lstwara repulse 99lstwara)`.
I am trying to make sure the program detects this line, it works but sometimes it can miss it, I want a code that will 100% detect it always anything that has **NOT FOUND** then detect it.

```
[INFO] RetroArch 1.7.7 (Git 52dd39f98a)
[INFO] Redirecting save file to "C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\saves\99lstwara.srm".
[INFO] Redirecting savestate to "C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\states\99lstwara.state".
[INFO] === Build =======================================
[INFO] CPU Model Name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
[INFO] Capabilities: MMX MMXEXT SSE1 SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4 SSE4.2 AVX AES 
[INFO] Built: May 10 2019
[INFO] Version: 1.7.7
[INFO] Git: 52dd39f98a
[INFO] =================================================
[INFO] Loading dynamic libretro core from: "C:\Users\popppz\AppData\Roaming\RetroArch\cores\mame2015_libretro.dll"
[INFO] [Overrides] no core-specific overrides found at C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\config\MAME 2015\MAME 2015.cfg.
[INFO] [Overrides] no content-dir-specific overrides found at C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\config\MAME 2015\rom test.cfg.
[INFO] [Overrides] no game-specific overrides found at C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\config\MAME 2015\99lstwara.cfg.
[INFO] [Shaders]: preset directory: C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\shaders\presets
[INFO] Environ SET_VARIABLES.
[INFO] [Remaps]: remap directory: C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\config\remaps
[INFO] [Remaps]: no game-specific remap found at C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\config\remaps\MAME 2015\99lstwara.rmp.
[INFO] [Remaps]: no content-dir-specific remap found at C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\config\remaps\MAME 2015\rom test.rmp.
[INFO] [Remaps]: no core-specific remap found at C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\config\remaps\MAME 2015\MAME 2015.rmp.
[INFO] Redirecting save file to "C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\saves\99lstwara.srm".
[INFO] Redirecting savestate to "C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\states\99lstwara.state".
[INFO] Environ GET_LOG_INTERFACE.
[INFO] Environ SYSTEM_DIRECTORY: "C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\system".
[libretro INFO] SYSTEM_DIRECTORY: C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\system[INFO] Environ CORE_ASSETS_DIRECTORY: "C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\downloads".
[libretro INFO] CONTENT_DIRECTORY: C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\downloads[libretro INFO] SAVE_DIRECTORY: C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\saves[INFO] Content loading skipped. Implementation will load it on its own.
[INFO] CRC32: 0x3841c5fe .
[INFO] Environ SET_PIXEL_FORMAT: RGB565.
[INFO] Skipping SRAM load..
[INFO] [RCHEEVOS]: Load task finished
[INFO] Version of libretro API: 1
[INFO] Compiled against API: 1
[libretro INFO] AV_INFO: width=320 height=240
[libretro INFO] AV_INFO: max_width=1600 max_height=1200
[libretro INFO] AV_INFO: aspect_ratio = 0.000000
[libretro INFO] AV_INFO: fps = 60.000000 sample_rate = 48000.000000
[INFO] [Audio]: Set audio input rate to: 47952.05 Hz.
[INFO] [Video]: Video @ 320x240
[INFO] [GL]: Found GL context: wgl
[INFO] [GL]: Detecting screen resolution 1920x1080.
[INFO] [WGL] extensions: WGL_EXT_depth_float WGL_ARB_buffer_region WGL_ARB_extensions_string WGL_ARB_make_current_read WGL_ARB_pixel_format WGL_ARB_pbuffer WGL_EXT_extensions_string WGL_EXT_swap_control WGL_EXT_swap_control_tear WGL_ARB_multisample WGL_ARB_pixel_ÌŠÙ[INFO] [WGL]: Adaptive VSync supported.
[INFO] [WGL]: wglSwapInterval(1)
[INFO] [GL]: Vendor: Intel, Renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600.
[INFO] [GL]: Version: 4.3.0 - Build 10.18.14.4414.
[INFO] [GL]: Using resolution 320x240
[INFO] [GL]: Default shader backend found: glsl.
[INFO] [Shader driver]: Using GLSL shader backend.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Checking GLSL shader support ...
[WARN] [GL]: Stock GLSL shaders will be used.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL vertex shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL fragment shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Linking GLSL program.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL vertex shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL fragment shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Linking GLSL program.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL vertex shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL fragment shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Linking GLSL program.
[INFO] Setting up menu pipeline shaders for XMB ... 
[INFO] [GLSL]: Compiling ribbon shader..
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL vertex shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL fragment shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Linking GLSL program.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Compiling simple ribbon shader..
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL vertex shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL fragment shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Linking GLSL program.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Compiling snow shader..
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL vertex shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL fragment shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Linking GLSL program.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Compiling modern snow shader..
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL vertex shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL fragment shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Linking GLSL program.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Compiling bokeh shader..
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL vertex shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL fragment shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Linking GLSL program.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Compiling snowflake shader..
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL vertex shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Found GLSL fragment shader.
[INFO] [GLSL]: Linking GLSL program.
[INFO] [GL]: Using 4 textures.
[INFO] [GL]: Loaded 1 program(s).
[INFO] [GL]: Using GL_RGB565 for texture uploads.
[INFO] [XInput]: Found XInput v1.3.
[INFO] [DINPUT]: Enumerating joypads ...
[INFO] [DINPUT]: Done enumerating joypads ...
[INFO] [Joypad]: Found joypad driver: "dinput".
[INFO] [Font]: Using font rendering backend: freetype.
[INFO] [Video]: Found display server: win32
[INFO] [XAudio2]: Requesting 64 ms latency, using 64 ms latency.
[INFO] [Menu]: Found menu display driver: "gl".
[ERROR] Failed to create rendering backend: freetype.
Failed to open C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\assets\ozone\regular.ttf: No such file or directory
[ERROR] Failed to create rendering backend: stb.
[INFO] [Font]: Using font rendering backend: bitmap.
[ERROR] Failed to create rendering backend: freetype.
Failed to open C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\assets\ozone\bold.ttf: No such file or directory
[ERROR] Failed to create rendering backend: stb.
[INFO] [Font]: Using font rendering backend: bitmap.
[INFO] [Menu]: Found menu display driver: "gl".
[ERROR] Failed to create rendering backend: freetype.
Failed to open C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\assets\xmb\monochrome\font.ttf: No such file or directory
[ERROR] Failed to create rendering backend: stb.
[INFO] [Font]: Using font rendering backend: bitmap.
[ERROR] Failed to create rendering backend: freetype.
Failed to open C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\assets\xmb\monochrome\font.ttf: No such file or directory
[ERROR] Failed to create rendering backend: stb.
[INFO] [Font]: Using font rendering backend: bitmap.
[WARN] [XMB] Asset missing: C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\assets\xmb\monochrome\png\retroarch.png
[WARN] [XMB] Critical asset missing, no icons will be drawn
[INFO] [LED]: LED driver = 'null' 0000000000AB03C0
[INFO] [MIDI]: Initializing ...
[INFO] [MIDI]: Input disabled.
[INFO] [MIDI]: Output disabled.
[INFO] [MIDI]: Initialized "winmm" driver.
[INFO] Loading history file: [C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\content_history.lpl].
[INFO] Loading history file: [C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\content_favorites.lpl].
[INFO] Loading history file: [C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\content_music_history.lpl].
[INFO] Loading history file: [C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\content_video_history.lpl].
[INFO] Loading history file: [C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\content_image_history.lpl].
[INFO] [GL]: VSync => on
[INFO] [WGL]: wglSwapInterval(1)
[INFO] Written to playlist file: C:\Users\popppz\.emulationstation\systems\retroarch\content_history.lpl
[libretro INFO] Starting game:C:\Users\popppz\Desktop\rom test\99lstwara.zip
[libretro INFO] Game name: 99lstwara, Game description: '99: The Last War (set 2)
[libretro INFO] Creating frontend for game: 99lstwara
[libretro INFO] Softlists: 0
SOURCE FILE: src/mame/drivers/kyugo.c
PARENT: repulse
NAME: 99lstwara
DESCRIPTION: '99: The Last War (set 2)
YEAR: 1985
MANUFACTURER: Crux / Proma
[libretro INFO] Screen orientation: VERTICAL
Value  not supported for option netdevprovider - falling back to auto
[libretro INFO] OSD initialization complete
repulse.b4 NOT FOUND (tried in 99lstwara repulse 99lstwara)
b.1j NOT FOUND (tried in 99lstwara repulse 99lstwara)
g.1h NOT FOUND (tried in 99lstwara repulse 99lstwara)
r.1f NOT FOUND (tried in 99lstwara repulse 99lstwara)
m1.2c NOT FOUND (tried in 99lstwara repulse 99lstwara)
Required files are missing, the game cannot be run.
```

I have this code

```vb
Open App.path & "\aretroarch.log" For Binary As #1
TextFileData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , TextFileData
Close #1

MyArray() = Split(TextFileData, "RetroArch")
'=======================================================
For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray())
    If InStr(MyArray(i), "lexplode") > 0 And InStr(MyArray(i), "Sample") > 0 Then
    ElseIf InStr(MyArray(i), "tried in") > 0 And InStr(MyArray(i), "NOT FOUND") > 0 Or InStr(MyArray(i), "NOT FOUND (tried") Or InStr(MyArray(i), "tried in") Or InStr(MyArray(i), "NOT FOUND") Or InStr(MyArray(i), "NOT FOUND") > 0 And InStr(MyArray(i), "tried in") > 0 Then
```

or this code

```vb
    ElseIf InStr(MyArray(i), "NOT FOUND") > 0 And InStr(MyArray(i), "tried in") > 0 Then
```

Is there a better way doing this as I have few lines of `if` to detect any string that has `NOT FOUND`.

Comment: Why are you splitting on `retroarch`?  You talk about "lines" but the resulting array will not have entries that correspond to lines in the text file because of the way you split it...

Comment: All of the "not found" values will be in the **same entry in the array** (the very last slot) because they all appear after the last `retroarch`.

Comment: what am doing is loading up txt data then looking for a string,now am using a ( if ) statement to check if it exist as you can se in main post, what other ways i can do to check

Comment: You think you are "missing" entries, but instead I don't think you understand what is being produced by the Split() call.  Try this and see what you get: `For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray)     Debug.Print(MyArray(i))     Next`

Comment: You think you are "missing ( maybe )

Comment: As far as I remember, the VB6 split() function can only split by a single character. I would have to verify that with my VB6 environment at home (can only check in the evening)

Comment: VB splits on one string. The string can be more than one character. Often it is `vbcrlf`. People often want it to split on more than one string (as an OR), that it doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

I see you use channels. Maybe FileSystemObject could help you

> https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).